# How to see which foreign key a dimension is linked from?

Tags: powerpivot, dimensional-modeling

I have a fact table with a "value". The fact table has two foreign keys "Job Manager" and "Project Director" which both link to the PersonKey in the DimPerson table.  This DimPerson table has person names etc.  How can I see the value by Job Manager?  I can only see by person name but that doesn't tell me whether they are Job Manager or Project Director but both are totalled together.  Using powerpivot how can I see the value by Job Manager? or value by Project Director?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one active relationship between tables in PowerPivot. To use a non-active relationship, you can create a calculated measure that references it.

You would have a relationship from FactTable to DimPerson based on the job manager (make this the active relationship) and another relationship from FactTable to DimPerson based on the project director (inactive relationship).

Then you would create a two measures that look something like:

```
ValueByJobManager:= Sum(FactTable[Value])

ValueByProjectDirector:= Calculate(Sum(FactTable[Value]),USERRELATIONSHIP(FactTable[ProjectDirectorKey],DimPerson[PersonKey]))
```

Here's a good blog post on the subject: http://www.leehbi.com/2012/03/new-features-in-powerpivot-v2/